# Prove this field extension is separable

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, separable-extension

Let $F \subset G_i \subset E, (i=1,2)$ where $E$ is normal and finite dimensional over $F$.  Assume $E$ is separable over $G_1$ and $G_2$.  Prove $E$ is separable over $G_1 \cap G_2$

There is a hint to use this theorem that states that a finite dimensional field extension is Galois iff it is normal and separable.
I think that this means we need to show that $G_i \subset E$ are Galois, which in this case is equivalent to showing that the extensions are normal.  I have a proposition that states that any intermediate field extension is normal so these extensions are normal and therefore Galois since we are given separable.  I do not see how $G_1, G_2 \subset E$ being Galois implies that their intersection is separable.  Is the intersection of two Galois extensions Galois or am I supposed to just use the definition of separable (in which case, why did I even find they are Galois), to show  that $E$ is separable over $G_1 \cap G_2$?

Comment: To show $G_i \subseteq E$ is Galois, note that if $E$ is Galois over $F$, then $E$ is also Galois over every intermediate field of $E/F$.

Comment: @D_S would $G_1 \cap G_2$ be an intermediate field extension since obviously $F \subset G_1 \cap G_2 \subset E$?  Then I could use your hint, which I proved in another question